# LuaJIT pointers and Garbage Collection

Tags: c, pointers, lua, garbage-collection, luajit

I am trying to fully understand what LuaJIT's garbage collector will handle with FFI and what I have to manage manually so I am sure to get no leakage.

Reading [LuaJIT FFI Semantics Docs](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html) about the garbage collector are the following assertions true?:

1. If an array is allocated using `ffi.new('float[?]',n)` then the gc can track its references and collect as necessary?
2. Using `ffi.malloc(sizeof('float[n]'))` must be manually handled such as ffi.free or provide a "finalizer" such as `local p = ffi.gc(ffi.malloc(sizeof('float[n]')), ffi.free)`?
3. If a library loaded with ffi.load contained a function `float * example(void);` and the library is loaded into namespace `Ex` then in

   `local ptr=Ex.example()`

   `ptr` is storing a pointer and when no references to ptr exist, gc will 
   collect `ptr` and memory will be leaked?
4. `ffi.gc(ptr, ffi.free)` lets the garbage collector know that ptr is indeed a pointer and the memory it points to can be reclaimed when ptr itself has no references?

[In saying](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_semantics.html)

> Memory areas returned by C functions (e.g. from malloc()) must be
>   manually managed, of course (or use ffi.gc()). Pointers to cdata
>   objects are indistinguishable from pointers returned by C functions
>   (which is one of the reasons why the GC cannot follow them).

Is it meant that even though the namespace that C library functions are given to the FFI in knows the return value to be a pointer, garbage collection cannot act autonomously performing (4)?

What is meant by Mike Pall [when he says](https://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/ffinew-vs-ffiCmalloc-speed,1)

> "But even if that function [ffi.gc()] were compiled ... the GC will
>   have to call the finalizer eventually, which is costly."

is he just referring to the function call to `ffi.free` in this case? If so, how would `ffi.new` get around this overhead?

Comment: 1 - Yes, 2 - Yes, 3 - Yes, 4 - not exactly. `ffi.gc(some_cdata, user_func)` just calls `user_func(some_cdata)` when last reference disappears.  You can use this for automatically free the memory.  Or for something else depending on your function.

Comment: Any user function invocation is costly.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for answering. I thought this was dead. Anyways, it seems there is no danger in thinking in the way as in (4) right? For example, `function New_Array(size) local ptr=ffi.cast('float*', ffi.malloc(ffi.sizeof(float)*size)) return ffi.gc(ptr, ffi.free) end` could hide everything and the end-user would believe Lua is a dynamic language with arrays just like Python (of course this would have odd behavior with malloc keeping the stale data but you get the idea of the example without `new()`)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Any idea how the JIT compiler manages to (mostly?) eliminate the overhead to functions in a C namespace that are not cached? Or, do you know if ffi.gc is compiled in the latest LuaJIT release as  Mike Pall claimed all those years ago in the link in my quesiton?

Comment: What are the benefits of using `ffi.C.malloc` instead of native optimized `ffi.new`? About whether `ffi.gc` is JIT-compiled or not you'd better ask Mike.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff `new` is like calloc. In my use case, I don't need the data 0 initialized in the case of VLAs and was hoping that I can get the bonus of the JIT compilation with the slight boost of `malloc` over `calloc`

Comment: Did you benchmarked it?  Is `ffi.C.malloc` (external function) really faster than `ffi.new` (internal JIT-optimized function) for arrays of your size?

Comment: Also, and iirc, `new` uses LJ memory pool (1 or 2Gb-limited), while `malloc`-allocated blocks do not add to that limitation, so you can malloc total of > 1Gb.

Comment: @user3125367 Thanks, this is true also. Not an issue in my use case though

Comment: Returning to this interesting topic, it seems that this answers your last question: https://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/ffinew-vs-ffiCmalloc-speed,4 (the same thread you linked)

Comment: @user3125367 I think my question really comes down to whether the overhead of garbage collection with using malloc (if it remains in the version I'm using which I'll have to check in the latest pre-compiled love version) is more or less than the allocation using new (calloc ?)...

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff If you would, post a summary of your comments as an answer and I will gladly accept to close this. I think that's a fine enough answer.